Call log file viewer from T-SQL
I am viewing historic stored procedures in SQL Server by opening "Job Activity Monitor":

Right click on my job and select "View history":

which returns a table, which I then export as a log file


I then proceed to parse the log files in other applications and monitoring purposes.
Is there a way to extract this information using a SQL query, so I can automate this extraction?
I tried EXEC dbo.sp_help_jobhistory @job_id =  N'blahblahblah', but the results are not broken into steps.
I tried exec sp_help_jobstep @job_id =  N'blahblahblah' to show the steps of the specific job_id, but I do not know how to join this to the table shown above.
Is there a way around this?

Those aren't historical stored procdedures... Those are historical logs of Agent Jobs.

Check out tables: msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory and msdb.dbo.sysjobstepslogs

I do not have these tables when I run select * from msdb.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES

What happens when you run: select top 30 * from msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory

The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'sysjobhistory', database 'msdb', schema 'dbo'. Presumably I will need permissions then

I will talk to my DBA then, as it is same account I used to view the images

Try: EXEC dbo.sp_help_jobhistory @job_id = N'X-Y-Z', @mode='full' The default mode doesn't return interesting stuff

@siggemannen That worked! Thanks. Put it as solution and I will accept it

As an extra, is it possible to see more history than 30 days?

Yes, if you set the retention period to more than 30 days; of course, you can receeate data that's already been deleted.

You can use:
EXEC dbo.sp_help_jobhistory @job_id = N'X-Y-Z', @mode='full'

to get more details the same way SQL Agent does.
As for your question:

As an extra, is it possible to see more history than 30 days

this is a setting for SQL Agent, so you have to control it there: right click on SQL Server Agent -> Properties -> History -> Remove agent history.

Personally, i prefer to use: "Max job history log size" and "maximum job history rows" which ensures every job has decent history
Note, that it might consume a lot of space if you keep the logs forever :)
